# How to Set RAILS_ENV Permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to deploy my rails app to my production server.  However my app won't use any of my production config.

I am manually setting RAILS_ENV using:

export RAILS_ENV=production

Then when I run echo $RAILS_ENV I am returned production but only for that bash session.  I have also added export RAILS_ENV=production in my .bashrc file, however still when I echo rails_env it returns blank.  This means that when my rails app runs it uses development config.

How can I set this so that my rails app will use my production config?  Preferably so that it is permanent so that I don't have to keep setting it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want system wide or a specific user?

Comment: Please specify which deployment solution do you use? Heroku, Capistrano, etc.

Comment: I use Capistrano with an Nginx/Unicorn server.  System wide would be great thanks!

Comment: Also note, your .bash_profile and .bashrc only load on new login sessions.  Adding it there won't take effect until you reconnect.  See my answer for your system wide setup, which is what you really need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it system wide, add it to the /etc/profile file, or create a new file in /etc/profile.d and add as

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks mate!  That's exactly what I needed.  Although when I set that I now get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong error"... Is this a common problem when changing to production environment?

Comment: Fixed it!  Changed this from false to true in production.rb

config.consider_all_requests_local       = true